# 3D Sphere isn't rendered properly

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, p5.js

I programmed a 3d sphere in javascript using p5.js and isn't rendered properly. You can see a lack of color in the last meridian and all the sphere isn't colored in the right manner. I tried a lot of things to fix this and isn't working.

Here's a image of what happen:

[image]

So why this happen?

Can you fix this?

Here's the code:

```js
var points;
var total = 25;
var r = 150;

function setup()
{
  createCanvas(600, 400, WEBGL);
  colorMode(HSB);
  points = new Array(total + 1);

  for (let i = 0; i <= total; i++)
  {
    points[i] = new Array(total);
    var lon = map(i, 0, total, -PI, PI);
    for (let j = 0; j <= total; j++)
    {
      points[i][j] = new p5.Vector();
      var lat = map(j, 0, total, - (PI /2), (PI / 2));
      points[i][j].x = r * sin(lon) * cos(lat);;
      points[i][j].y = r * sin(lon) * sin(lat);
      points[i][j].z = r * cos(lon);
    }
  }

}

angle = 0;

function draw()
{
  background(0);
  fill(255)
  rotateX(angle);
  stroke(255);
  for (let i = 0; i < total; i++)
  {
    <!-- noFill(); -->
    var hue = map(i, 0, total, 0, 255);
    beginShape();
    for (let j = 0; j < total; j++)
    {
      fill(hue, 255, 255);
      vertex(points[i][j+1].x, points[i][j+1].y, points[i][j+1].z);
      vertex(points[i+1][j+1].x, points[i+1][j+1].y, points[i+1][j+1].z);
      vertex(points[i][j+1].x, points[i][j+1].y, points[i][j+1].z);
      vertex(points[i][j].x, points[i][j].y, points[i][j].z);
    }
    endShape();
  }
  angle += 0.01;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you try putting ```beginShape``` and ```endShape``` inside the inner for-loop, and using ```beginShape(QUADS)```? It looks like you want to draw surface pieces with 4 corners each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code:

1. If you use [`beginShape`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/beginShape), the default primitive type is a large polygon, but you want to draw `QUADS`

   <s>`beginShape();`</s>

   ```js
   beginShape(QUADS);
   ```
2. The vertices are wrong because `points[i][j+1]` is given twice, but `points[i+1][j]` is missing. Correct is:

   ```js
   vertex(points[i][j+1].x, points[i][j+1].y, points[i][j+1].z);
   vertex(points[i+1][j+1].x, points[i+1][j+1].y, points[i+1][j+1].z);
   vertex(points[i+1][j].x, points[i+1][j].y, points[i+1][j].z);
   vertex(points[i][j].x, points[i][j].y, points[i][j].z);
   ```

Also note that `beginShape`/`endshape` can be moved out of the outer loop. This way you don't have to start a new shape continuously, but the complete sphere can be drawn at once.

```js
var points;
var total = 25;
var r = 150;

function setup()
{
    createCanvas(600, 400, WEBGL);
    colorMode(HSB);
    points = new Array(total + 1);

    for (let i = 0; i <= total; i++)
    {
        points[i] = new Array(total);
        var lon = map(i, 0, total, -PI, PI);
        for (let j = 0; j <= total; j++)
        {
            points[i][j] = new p5.Vector();
            var lat = map(j, 0, total, - (PI /2), (PI / 2));
            points[i][j].x = r * sin(lon) * cos(lat);;
            points[i][j].y = r * sin(lon) * sin(lat);
            points[i][j].z = r * cos(lon);
        }
    }
}

var angle = 0;

function draw()
{
    background(0);
    fill(255)
    rotateX(angle);
    stroke(255);
    beginShape(QUADS);
    for (let i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        var hue = map(i, 0, total, 0, 255);
        fill(hue, 255, 255);
        for (let j = 0; j < total; j++)
        {
            vertex(points[i][j+1].x, points[i][j+1].y, points[i][j+1].z);
            vertex(points[i+1][j+1].x, points[i+1][j+1].y, points[i+1][j+1].z);
            vertex(points[i+1][j].x, points[i+1][j].y, points[i+1][j].z);
            vertex(points[i][j].x, points[i][j].y, points[i][j].z);
        }
    }
    endShape();
    angle += 0.01;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your explanation!! It's clear and correct!! A lot of thanks!